# Моментальное изменение параметров в css анимации

Tags: css, css-animation

Есть анимация

```
@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 0
  }
  100% {
    width:0;
  }
}
```

И я хочу, например, после 50% моментально применить width: 100% и ещё пару параметров, color, background. Я понимаю, что можно сделать, например, так:

```
50.001% {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Но можно ли избежать такого... колхоза? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно повторить то же самое значение, не обязательно добавлять .001%

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov В моём примере, если повторить 50%, то всё сломается (будет переливаться плавно то, что должно меняться резко). https://codepen.io/xpomix/pen/RwjxgbN

Comment: пожалуй, это самое рациональное решение, с которым я знаком — использовать 50.0001%. можно выдумывать велосипед, но зачем